# Работа с базой Vuforia

Tags: unity3d, vuforia

Я еще не начал разрабатовать приложение так как нету еще опыта с unity и vuforia, но хочу спросить пару вопросов и советов у более опытных.

Те кто знают в Vuforia есть своя база "меток", с помощью которых показывают на экране AR обьекты.

1. При "рендеринге" приложения заранее заливаю нужные AR обьекты и их "метки" с базой Vuforia и все готовый apk. Но в будущем когда буду добавлять новые обьекты и метки надо заново "рендерить" приложение и обновлять в play market или можно как-то это по сети устроить?
2. Есть ли возможность с приложения пользователям загружать свои "метки" и AR обьекты в эту базу Vuforia, и отображалось у других пользователей тоже? Как маски в инсте кто-то создает, другие пользуются.

В голове у меня только одна мысль на второй вопрос, брать и писать какой-то скрипт-бота который якобы добавляю я, но за меня это делает скрипт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Vuforia есть сервис Cloud Databases. Это позволяет создавать и хранить метки (объекты, цели, targets) независимо от кода приложения.
Последовательность действий такаяя:

1. Создать новый проект в Unity.
2. Через Windows -> Package Mаnager установить Vuforia Engine AR (стабильная версия на январь 2021 - 8.1.12)
3. Создать лицензионный ключ для своего проекта ([на официальном сайте](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Vuforia-License-Manager.html)).
4. В окне Hierarchy удалить объект Main Camera, добавить Vuforia Engine -> AR Camera.
5. В настройках AR камеры в Vuforia Configuration ввести созданный лицензионный ключ.
6. Создать Vuforia Engine -> Cloud Image -> Cloud Recognition и Vuforia Engine -> Cloud Image -> Image Target.
7. Создать облачную базу данных Cloud Database [по инструкции](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Work-with-Cloud-Databases.html).
8. В Cloud Recognition вставить ключи созданной базы данных.
9. Создать и добавить к Cloud Recognition скрипт SimpleCloudHandler с кодом:

   ```
   using UnityEngine.UI;
   using UnityEngine;
   using Vuforia;
   using System.Collections;

    public class SimpleCloudHandler : MonoBehaviour, IObjectRecoEventHandler
    {
        private CloudRecoBehaviour mCloudRecoBehaviour;

    void Start()
    {
        mCloudRecoBehaviour = GetComponent<CloudRecoBehaviour>();

        if (mCloudRecoBehaviour)
        {
            mCloudRecoBehaviour.RegisterEventHandler(this);
        }
        mCloudRecoBehaviour.CloudRecoEnabled = true;

      }

    public void OnInitialized(TargetFinder targetFinder)
    {
        Debug.Log("Инициализировано Cloud Reco");
    }
    public void OnInitError(TargetFinder.InitState initError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ошибка инициализации Cloud Reco " + initError.ToString());
    }
    public void OnUpdateError(TargetFinder.UpdateState updateError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ошибка обновления Cloud Reco " + updateError.ToString());
    }

    public void OnStateChanged(bool scanning)
    {

        if (scanning)
        {
            ObjectTracker tracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();
            tracker.GetTargetFinder<ImageTargetFinder>().ClearTrackables(false);
        }

    }

    public void OnNewSearchResult(TargetFinder.TargetSearchResult targetSearchResult)
    {
        TargetFinder.CloudRecoSearchResult cloudRecoSearchResult = (TargetFinder.CloudRecoSearchResult)targetSearchResult;

       string nameOfTarget = cloudRecoSearchResult.TargetName;
       string metadataOfTarget = cloudRecoSearchResult.MetaData;

        //Используйте эти данные, как вам нужно, например, создайте элемент UI Text и выведите на экран название распознанного объекта

    }
   ```

   }
10. Добавляйте и удаляйте объекты в облачной базе данных, сколько хотите. Все изменения соответственно автоматически будут отображаться в работе приложения.
    Успехов!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да за 5 месяцев я кое как нашел этот ответ, но все же спасибо за то что ответили, возможно кому то поможет.